# Angular Cli project Cannot find module react-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: angular, webpack, react-bootstrap

I'd like to use the react-bootstrap-typeahead npm module in my Angular2 cli generated project. Now, I'm quite new to Angular and am not sure where I went wrong. I followed the npm modules installation instructions but cannot get around this issue.
Does anymody know who to resolve this please?

This is my environment:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4
node: 6.9.5
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
@ngtools/webpack: 1.2.3
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "react": "^15.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^1.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack": "2.2.0-rc.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.50",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Typeahead
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

command line =>

```
ng build
```

output =>

```
ERROR in C:/dev/projects/test-app/src/app/app.module.ts (8,25): Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap-typeahead'.
```

File structure of react-bootstrap-typeahead:

```
24/03/2017  01:43 PM    <DIR>          .
24/03/2017  01:43 PM    <DIR>          ..
24/03/2017  01:43 PM               195 CHANGELOG.md
24/03/2017  01:43 PM    <DIR>          css
24/03/2017  01:43 PM    <DIR>          dist
24/03/2017  01:43 PM    <DIR>          docs
24/03/2017  01:43 PM    <DIR>          lib
24/03/2017  01:43 PM             1,091 LICENSE.md
24/03/2017  01:43 PM             4,416 package.json
24/03/2017  01:43 PM             3,262 README.md
```

Comment: In your project, have you done an `npm install` since adding the typeahead package?

Comment: Hi Devon, yes I did - multiple times too

Comment: I see that the typeahead module is not in your list of dependencies, could you run `npm install --save react-bootstrap-typeahead` in your project and verify that it was added to your `package.json`?

Comment: sorry, I used a blank project to showcase the error. I've installed the package now and updated the package.json above.

Comment: I see that you're using the angular-cli, when running `ng serve` do you get the same error?

Comment: I noticed that the structure of the react-bootstrap-typeahead module is different than other modules. Could that be the cause for it not being found/recognized?? (I added the directory view above)

Comment: Apologies, as far as I know, React components won't work out of the box with Angular..I completely overlooked the `react` in your package name. If you are looking for a simple typeahead style library, I would suggest angular2-bootstrap typeahead by Valor Software. https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: yes, ng serve comes back with the same error msg.

Comment: thanks Devon, I'll check that out

Comment: The feature I liked about the react-bootstrap-typeahead module was the multi select. Does anybody know if there's a similar module that is supported by Angular2?